# EXEC in T-SQL ignores CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

With any version of Sql Server, I cannot understand why, in the following script, EXEC returns the result of GetDate(). I expected no result.

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
DECLARE @sql_select  nvarchar(150) = 'SELECT GetDate()';
DECLARE @sql_select2 nvarchar(150) = NULL;
SELECT  @sql_select + @sql_select2
EXEC(@sql_select + @sql_select2)
```

Comment: try adding a `SELECT  @sql_select2 = null;` before your first select statement -- maybe assigning null is not allowed in a declaration.

Comment: Weird.. Assigning the concatenation result to variable makes the query to work as expected `declare @sql varchar(900)
SELECT  @sql = @sql_select + @sql_select2
EXEC(@sql)`

Comment: @Hogan, assigning null in the declaration is allowed and redundant. An unassigned variable is null. The problem is not that. The problem is the inconsistent behaviour of the operator +

Comment: Just left my computer so can't test myself right now, but what happens if you add another string/variable with not null value: `exec(@sql_select + @sql_select2 + ', 1')`? Is everything after a null ignored?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, it's not ignored. the null variables are converted into empty strings or simply ignored. your query returns two columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think, inside `exec`, `NULL` is converted into empty string. Here is an easier example

```
DECLARE @sql_select2 varchar(200) ;

exec('select 1' + @sql_select2)
```

returns `1` though it is concatenated with a `NULL` value.

But when we do the concatenation outside it works as expected.

```
DECLARE @sql_select NVARCHAR(150) = 'SELECT GetDate()';
DECLARE @sql_select2 NVARCHAR(150) = NULL;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)

SET @sql = @sql_select + @sql_select2

EXEC(@sql)
```

returns nothing

Comment: You may also think that SQL Server ignores NULL values, but my question is why. From my perspective the behaviour is inconsistent. I wonder if there's a formal explanation and/or an official link.