# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql, sql-server, heidisql

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         192.168.62.245
-- Server version:               Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8
-- Server OS:                    Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)
-- HeidiSQL Version:             9.5.0.5196
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES  */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


-- Dumping database structure for mjDB
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "mjDB";
USE "mjDB";

-- Dumping structure for table mjDB.PushNotificationLog
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "PushNotificationLog" (
    "pushNotificationLogId" INT(10,0) NOT NULL,
    "itemType" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "itemId" INT(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "servicemanId" INT(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "title" VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "body" VARCHAR(4000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "tranId" INT(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "createdBy" INT(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "createdDate" DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("pushNotificationLogId")
);
```

I exported this one from HeidiSQL updated to 19/12/2017, when I try to run this on SQL Server 2014 I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near 'mjDB'.
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Database 'mjDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: Which version of `Sql Server` you are using ? Syntax you have used is introduced in `Sql Server 2016`

Comment: I don't think SQL Server has a `INT(10,0)` data type. Looks like you are trying to run a MySQL script against SQL Server

Comment: There is no `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in SQL Server. Check the documentation ([`CREATE DATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql) | [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql)). Newer versions (but not 2014) support syntax like `DROP ... IF EXISTS` for some objects, and `CREATE OR REPLACE` (for modules only), but nothing like what you have exists in any version.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - [OT] Any thoughts on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080922/exec-in-t-sql-ignores-concat-null-yields-null/48081135#48081135

Comment: A well-disguised "please convert my MySQL query to SQL Server" post here!

Comment: @JacobH so polite, but it is not working neither in MySQL

Comment: mysql ver 15.1 distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB, this issue in MYSQL: /*!40101 SET NAMES */

Comment: How did you create that script? If that was generated in HeidiSQL, then it's clearly a HeidiSQL bug - it should generate SQL that works with the database you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just like you said, I used HeidiSQL, there are about 3000 script lines more that I didn't write it here, and now I'm not sure how to convert them to any format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create table syntax is wrong if you are using SQL Server. Change the code like this if you wish to check the table existence before creating

```
IF object_id('PushNotificationLog') IS NULL
BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE [PushNotificationLog] 
     (
         pushNotificationLogId INT NOT NULL,
         itemType VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         itemId INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         servicemanId INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         title VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         body VARCHAR(4000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         tranId INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         createdBy INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         createdDate DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,

         PRIMARY KEY (pushNotificationLogId)
    );
END
```

You can also do the check by checking the existence in the view `sys.tables`

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'PushNotificationLog')
BEGIN

END
```

Similarly Check in the **master.sys.databases** table for the existence of Database

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'mjDB')
    BEGIN

    END
```

Comment: (1) Please don't use `sysdatabases` but instead use `sys.databases`. (2) Why are you using string delimiters around every single column and table name? Don't you find that hard to read (and perhaps ambiguous to readers who expect those to be string literals instead of identifiers)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand. Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Msg 2724, Level 16, State 4, Line 4
Parameter or variable 'pushNotificationLogId' has an invalid data type.

I got this issue

Comment: You don't have to specify a size for INT and DateTime data types. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes (') instead of double quotes (")
Remove the quotes from the identifiers (DatabaseName, TableName)
Replace the quotes in the column names with square brackets ([])

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [master].sys.databases
    WHERE [name] = 'mjDB'
)
    BEGIN CREATE DATABASE mjDB; END
GO

USE mjDB;
GO

-- Dumping structure for table mjDB.PushNotificationLog
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.PushNotificationLog', 'U') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE dbo.PushNotificationLog
        (
            [PushNotificationLogID] INT NOT NULL
            , [ItemType] VARCHAR(20)
            , [ItemID] INT
            , [ServicemanID] INT
            , [Title] VARCHAR(100)
            , [Body] VARCHAR(4000)
            , [TranId] INT
            , [CreatedBy] INT
            , [CreatedDate] DATETIME
            , CONSTRAINT PK__PushNotificationLog PRIMARY KEY ([pushNotificationLogId])
        );
    END
GO
```

Comment: Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Database 'mjDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: I got that message